# What kind of JVM support is there for Modern UI apps?

Tags: windows-8, java, desktop, modern-ui, jvm

Obviously, the JRE and Java applications and applets still work on the Desktop version of Windows 8. But is there a way to develop a Modern UI application in Java, or another JVM based language such as Clojure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only create metro style apps with C#, VB, JavaScript and C++. There is currently no support for authoring metro style applications with Java.

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454019/creating-windows-metro-style-apps-with-java

Comment: There isn't any reason this couldn't be done in theory.  Of course Microsoft would likely not accept them.  There isn't anything preventing you from importing the respected WinRT dlls and calling only WinRT library functions, to design the application.  At the end of the they applications would NOT be Modern UI applications since Java CANNOT duplicate the Win32 Forms and Window classes functionality.

Comment: Yes.  It seems on far with other business decisions Microsoft has made in regards to the platform.  Forcing everything to use Win32 Forms and Window classes keeps everything looking familiar to the user.  You can always write a program as usual for the desktop, but then you can't port to RT.